# Typeahead not showing all data (v0.11.1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I am using Typeahead v0.11.1

I have the following script to fetch data from the server in the format of key-value pairs, with keys 'id' and 'name'.

When I searched using a particular query, say 'trading', the results doesn't show all entries with the word trading, even though it hasn't exceeded the default limit of 5 results.

For instance, querying `trading` returns the result

> Xujoq Marketing Trading Pte Ltd

while the following are not displayed

> Masterful Energy Trading Pte Ltd
>
> Masterful Energy Trading SA
>
> Halorey Trading LLC

```js
var search = $("#inputProvider");
var positions = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: 'sql_getentities.php',
    filter: function(datum) {
      var matches = [];
      var substrRegex = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(search.val()), "i");
      $.each(datum, function(i, data) {
        if (substrRegex.test(data.name)) {
          matches.push(data);
        }
      });
      console.log(JSON.stringify(datum));
      return matches;
    }
  }
});
positions.initialize();
search.typeahead({
  highlight: true
}, {
  name: "entities",
  templates: {
    suggestion: function(data) {
      return '<div>' + data.name + '</div>';
    },
    notFound: function() {
      return '<div class="tt-suggestion">Entity not found. Click <a href="/home/">here</a> to add entity.</div>';
    }
  },
  source: positions.ttAdapter(),
  display: function(data) {
    return data.name;
  }
}).bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj, datum, name) {
  $('#hiddenEntityID').val(datum.id);
});

function escapeRegExp(str) {
 return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inputProvider">
```

json output from `sql_getentities.php`

```
[
{"id":"00000000009","name":"Xujoq Marketing Trading Pte Ltd"},
{"id":"00000000010","name":"Delpo Singapore Pte Ltd"},
{"id":"00000000013","name":"Ingredia Singapore Pte. Ltd."},
{"id":"00000000003","name":"Masterful Energy Trading Pte Ltd"},
{"id":"00000000004","name":"Masterful Energy Trading SA"},
{"id":"00000000011","name":"Yugsol GP Asia Pte Ltd"},
{"id":"00000000012","name":"Yugsol GP GmbH"},
{"id":"00000000008","name":"Jenex Holdings (Asia) Pte Ltd"},
{"id":"00000000005","name":"Jenex International Pte Ltd"},
{"id":"00000000007","name":"Jenex Limited"},
{"id":"00000000001","name":"Halorey Pte Ltd"},
{"id":"00000000002","name":"Halorey Trading LLC"}
]
```

The only solution I found around this fix is to set the limit option in Typeahead to more than the total number of data returned from `sql_getentities.php`. However, when the dataset grows, the dropdown list will become exceedingly long, which is not the objective.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: You are doing the matching yourself in your filter method.  You need to look at what is going into the filter method and how each item is being evaluated.

Comment: @whipdancer I've checked the variable `matches` that is returned from filter. The output is correct as I want it to be. But when the data is passed to Typeahead, for some reason things get left out.

Comment: can you create a fiddle to demonstrate the problem?